# plane graphs cobordism

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I am looking for references for results on cobordisms of plane graphs; by plane graph cobordism I mean a surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \times [0,1]$ interpolating in  between two plane graphs $G_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0\}$ and $G_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \times \{1\}$, such that for all but a finite number of critical points in $[0,1]$, $S \cap \{t\}$ is a plane graph.